# Using 2012 iMac as a monitor for 2020 M1 MacBook Air

Tags: display, external-display, imac, macbook-air

I have an old iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2012) and i want to use it as a second monitor for my new MacBook Air (M1, 2020).

Is it possible without latency or any quality loss?

If it is, what are the options of doing it, and did any one test it and can confirm some method that really works?

Comment: Have you tried to simply connect the monitor to the device?  The only real requirement is that the MacBook Air (M1) has a video output port that the monitor also supports.

Comment: The macbook air has only a usb-c port.

Comment: So unless the monitor also supports video over USB Type-C you won't be able to connect the monitor to that device.

Comment: The iMac would do it, but the 2020 MBA won't. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389348/what-are-the-requirements-to-use-imac-screen-as-a-second-monitor-target-displa/389357#389357 for the full story.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin ! any hacks to solve this?

Comment: No, it's simply no longer a function. They won't build the bridge necessary for it to work.